# Small caps font is not enabled with fontspec and MinionPro

Tags: luatex, fontspec, small-caps

I can't make lualatex generate small caps font when I use MinionPro as my main font:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,justified,nobib,notoc]{tufte-book}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\title{ABC}
\author{Arthur Author}

\begin{document}
\newthought{This is a smart new thought} and it shines.
\setmainfont{MinionPro}[SmallCapsFont = {MinionPro},%
             SmallCapsFeatures = {RawFeature={+smcp} }]
\newthought{This is a stupid new thought} and it sucks.

\end{document}
```

\newthought of tufte-book uses \textsc, and it works for the default font, but doesn't when MinionPro is selected.  In the example above "This is a smart new thought" is rendered in small-caps, but "This is a stupid new thought" is rendered in normal MinionPro font (**not** small-caps).

What do I do wrong?

I tracked it down to the minimum test case. Small-caps and `MinionPro` do not work with `\textls` of `microtype`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}

\setmainfont{MinionPro}%[Renderer = Basic]

\textls{\scshape{This is a stupid new thought}} and it sucks.

\end{document}
```

As it is `This is a stupid new thought` appears in normal font, **not** small-caps.

If `[Render = Basic]` is not commented out, `This is a stupid new thought` is in small-caps, but Th is rendered as `Th` ligature, with `h` in lower-case.

Comment: Two things I notice: 1) You need to load `fontspec` 2) I think the options in the `[]` brackets should go between `\setmainfont` and `{MinionPro}`

Comment: @darthbith (1) yes, (2) no, it's the *new* interface.

Comment: @Manuel Interesting, in what version did that change?

Comment: It seems to be a problem with `microtype` and `luaotfload`, the chosen fontname seems invalid when letterspacing is involved.

Comment: If I add `Renderer=Basic` it almost works, but the `Th` is wrong.

Comment: tufte-book loads fontspec when lualatex is used.

Comment: There was some kind of update to LuaTeX recently (in TeXLive 2014) and now the behavior seems a bit erratic (with weird error messages) but when it works I get small caps with Minion Pro as long as I don't use tufte-book (ie they work with the default classes and memoir).

Comment: @darthbith the format changed when TeXLive 2014 came out. The older ordering still works but the preferred form is to list the font name first and then whatever options you want. I'm guessing the thinking was that it makes it easier to see the typeface you're using at a glance and I agree -- I often have complicated options and multiple typefaces and looking to the ends of the line to find the name is annoying.

Comment: @dmakarov I tried your MWE with the TL 2014 luaotfload and it [looks fine to me](http://i.imgur.com/9PsEQRt.jpg). Both marked regions are in small caps, and the document does use Minion. Can you please post an image demonstrating what is wrong on your setup? Thanks.

Comment: @phg here is how it looks for me ![IMG](http://i59.tinypic.com/mr7kol.jpg)

Comment: @egreg *“the chosen fontname seems invalid when letterspacing is involved.”* -- What are you referring to? Minion Pro [works perfectly well](http://i.imgur.com/QB0VKDs.jpg) with both small caps and letterspacing enabled. Here’s the code: https://gist.github.com/70f8bbb8515ba71978b6

Comment: @dmakarov Can’t reproduce.
Please post the output of ``luaotfload-tool -V``, ``luaotfload-tool --find="MinionPro"``, and ``otfinfo -i FILENAME`` where *FILENAME* is the full path to the file output by the previous command.

Comment: `$ luaotfload-tool -V
... luaotfload-tool version "2.4-4"
database version "2.41"
Lua interpreter: stock; version "Lua 5.2"
Luatex SVN revision 4971
Luatex version 0.79.1
$ luaotfload-tool --find="MinionPro"
luaotfload | resolve : Font "MinionPro" found!
... "/Library/Fonts/MinionPro-Regular.otf"
$ otfinfo -i /Library/Fonts/MinionPro-Regular.otf
Family:              Minion Pro
Subfamily:           Regular
Full name:           MinionPro-Regular
PostScript name:     MinionPro-Regular
Version:             Version 2.030;PS 2.000;hotconv 1.0.51;makeotf.lib2.0.18671`

Comment: @phg I'm sorry for the messy comment. I don't know this mark-down language, and comments length is limited. Thanks for helping.

Comment: @phg the LaTeX source is here [test](https://gist.github.com/dmakarov/cf9b3458b15e9e84adb7#file-miniopro)

Comment: @dmakarov It might be easier to post the output on a paste site like https://gist.github.com/ http://pastebin.com/ -- they do a  much better job at preserving formatting than these puny comments. Btw. your luaotfload and luatex look fine and you have more recent Minion Pro than me. I have no idea why it doesn’t work for you.

Comment: @phg I added the lua* output in a comment to the code snippet of test.tex  here [test](https://gist.github.com/dmakarov/cf9b3458b15e9e84adb7#file-miniopro)  My texlive installation is most recent, with `tlmgr update -all` as of this morning.

Comment: If I use the default font the `\textls{\textsc{some text}}` works for me. But if I use either Minion Pro or Garamond Premier Pro the letter spacing works but it doesn't show as small caps.

Comment: @dmakarov Ah, the linked code does indeed lack small caps. You can try requesting letterspacing directly like so: ``\textsc{\addfontfeatures{RawFeature={letterspace=10}}foo bar baz}`` but I have no idea how to translate this into a more Fontspec’y / Latexnical idiom.

Comment: @phg Yes, I can make individual strings in small caps with MinionPro. The problem was to make `\newthought{}` of `tufte-book` class work with MinionPro, which reduces to `\textls\scshape` not working with MinionPro as main font for some reason.  I guess I can redefine `\newthought` all the way to workaround `textls` problem, but I was hoping to avoid that... :-)

Comment: @dmakarov and @phg each font I try `\textls{\textsc{some text}}` with will not produce the small caps though the letter spacing works. Again, the exception being if I don't use `\setmainfont` and just use the default type.

Comment: Argh, I kept forgetting the `[Renderer=Basic]` bit which does render the small caps properly. And yes I also get the "Th" ligated but making it `T\/h` renders it properly.

Comment: @phg The fontname I get ends with `+smcp;"+ls50` that doesn't seem good.

Comment: @egreg: Indeed. That is weird. I’m not that well informed about how things work on the Latex end, but my guess is that something (Fontspec? Microtype?) doesn’t get the feature string right. It should be something like ``+smcp;letterspace=5`` instead (I have no clue as to what the value 50 might mean in this context).

Comment: @phg I left a reply at your GitHub site with an example showing the font name that is formed.